# Inverse of cosine

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Always we talk about inverse of cosine in $[0 , \pi]$ interval but the cosine function also is one-to-one in $[\pi  , 2\pi] , [2\pi , 3\pi] , \dots$ . If we consider $[\pi  , 2\pi]$ interval the graph of $\arccos$ will be different from $[0 , \pi]$. Is this true ? And if it is true many formulas will change !

Comment: If we consider $[\pi,2\pi]$ yes the answer will be different. However the range arccosine is always kept between $[0,\pi]$

Comment: The formulas that would change would get extra $k\pi$ terms, just making things marginally more complicated. As there is no benefit, this is not done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use notation $$\cos_n\colon [n\pi,(n+1)\pi]\to[-1,1]$$ and observe the appropriate inverses $$\cos_n^{-1}\colon[-1,1]\to[n\pi,(n+1)\pi].$$ Define $\arccos = \cos_0^{-1}$ as usual. We want to inspect how $\cos_n^{-1}$ and $\arccos$ are related.

First of all, draw the graph of $\cos\colon\Bbb R\to [-1,1]$ and reflect it along the line $y = x$. This gives you graphs of all $\cos_n^{-1}$ in one plot. It is easy to observe that

$$\cos_n^{-1}(x)-n\pi - \frac\pi 2 = \begin{cases}\arccos x - \frac\pi 2, \ \text{$n$ even}\\
-(\arccos x - \frac\pi 2),\ \text{$n$ odd}\end{cases}$$

or combining it into single formula: $$\cos_n^{-1}x = (-1)^n(\arccos x - \frac\pi 2) + n\pi + \frac\pi 2$$

Thus, there is no essential difference between $\cos_n^{-1}$ for different $n$ (the graphs are just translated and/or reflected), all the analytic properties can be obtained from $\arccos$ and usually, you don't even want to be bothered with the above formula if you are, for example, solving some trigonometric equation. You just use periodicity to obtain all the solutions.

Comment: Thank you , very good and complete

Comment: Can we say $\sin_n^{-1}x = (-1)^n(\arcsin x - \frac\pi 2) + n\pi + \frac\pi 2$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W, you are welcome. Formula won't be the same for sine, try to work it out yourself (really, it is just drawing the graphs and moving parts up/down).

Comment: Okay , thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 1):

The graph will be different, no doubt. You have to realise that the inverse trigonometric functions are multivalued. So we have to specify a domain, so that they are one-to-one in that domain. Accordingly, if we change the domain, we will get a different graph. But the characteristics of the graph will be the same; it will only be laterally shifted along the $\theta$ axis.

$$\frac12=\sin 30^\circ=\sin 150^\circ= \ldots  $$

So, $$\arcsin \frac12=n\pi + (-1)^n\cdot \frac{\pi}{6}=30^\circ=150^\circ= \ldots $$

Hence, you see what actually happens.

Comment: I think this formula is wrong because for example $\arcsin \frac{1}{2} = \pi \pm \frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: @S.H.W Corrected it.

Comment: Thank you your answer is very good .